# How can I directly launch into a game server, my code doesn't work

Tags: c#, steam

```
public static void PlayGame()
{
    Process.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\steam\\steamapps\\common\\Arma 3\\arma3.exe",
        "-connect=server.altislife.co.uk:2302;");
}
```

I have a function, called `PlayGame`, when trying to join the server with these parameters and game path, I simply get stuck at a loading screen, signifying some sort of error.

Comment: The semi-colon at the end of the connect option looks like it probably shouldn't be there.

Comment: I would agree with @itsme86. Looking at the Arma 3 startup parameters, `-connect` is the IP to connect to (an IP wouldn't include that semi-colon). Also, there is a separate `-port` option. Maybe split the 2302 off into that?

Comment: Ahhh, Okay thankyou! I just thought because within the actual steam parameters field, you do require the semi colon with multiple parameters. If not, just me having a brainfart! :P